# Is there a way to control Pause or Grace period features through Huawei developer console?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to input the grace period into IAP setting. `InAppPurchaseDetails`, the `graceExpirationTime` field indicates the expiration time of the grace period. This sounds good but I’m not able to find `graceExpirationTime` field in “Server-side” related [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/iap-InAppPurchaseDetails) and Webhook notification payload as well. Is it available in the API’s consumed by the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Grace period function is not available yet. For details, please refer to [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/subscription-functions-0000001050130264#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050130264__section9656759154814)
[image]